# Android RSS Reader - Tutorial error

Tags: java, android, xml, rss, xml-parsing

I have spent the day researching Android RSS Readers.

I would like to parse a very simple XML file in my app. http://www.sportinglife.com/rss/transfer_wire.xml

There are several threads on this site answering RSS questions, such as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253788/simple-rss-parser-for-android. I have tried all the solutions in this but I keep getting errors in Eclipse when running the code.

I have found a recent IBM Tutorial from April 2012, which explains the code very well and offers a solution in just one class file. http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-androidxml/index.html

I have followed this tutorial step by step, but Eclipse throws the following error:

```
[Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Unexpected magic: [100, 101, 120, 10, 48, 49, 51, 0]
[FootballTransfers] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Unexpected magic: [100, 101, 120, 10, 48, 49, 51, 0]
```

Has anybody encountered this problem before? I have no idea what this error means.

I get the same error when I run the solutions offered in the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253788/simple-rss-parser-for-android thread.

Comment: http://samir-mangroliya.blogspot.in/p/android-customized-listview.html

Comment: @SamirMangroliya Thanks dude. I will give this a go and get back to you. I found this tutorial online, imported it into Eclipse. When I run, I get the 'Conversion to Dalvik format failed' message again. If the same happens for your solution, there is definitely something wrong with my IDE.

Comment: yes definately because this tuts working nice in my eclipse.

Comment: @SamirMangroliya Same error. I go to File -> New -> Other -> Android Project. Then I select 'Create project from existing source'. I chose the folder your solution is stored in. I then went to Window -> Clean. When I run the project, I get the same error I detailed in my answer. Can anybody help with this?

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/search?sugexp=chrome,mod=6&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=Conversion+to+Dalvik+format+failed%3A+Unable+to+execute+dex%3A

Comment: @SamirMangroliya It was a simple as restarting Eclipse! D'oh! Unfortunately I am behind a work internet proxy so I am unable to retrieve http://www.npr.org/rss/rss.php?id=1001 from the Emulator. I have stored it offline in my project folder: res/xml/feed.xml. How can I reference a local file in line 33 of your NewsMainActivity class? ".MyRssReadTask().execute("http://www.npr.org/rss/rss.php?id=1001");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pass inputstream instead of urls

```
 @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... urls) {

 arrayList = new NewsParser().getData(NewsMainActivity .this.getResources.openRawResourece(R.xml.feed));

            return null;
        }
```

and in getData method change parameter to InputStream.

```
 public List<NewsBean> getData(InputStream istream) {
    DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance()
                    .newDocumentBuilder();

            System.out.println("Builder : " + builder);

            Document doc = builder.parse(istream);
    Document doc = builder.parse(istream);
.....
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help dude! I got my RSS Feed working perfectly on my app :-) If you have the code so that images could be parsed as well, please share!